# iPad Push Notification

Tags: ipad, apple-push-notifications

I am using iPad with iOS version 4.1.2, I have downloaded sample iPushTester application from iTunes, while running application for push notification I am getting error as

> push failed due to network error

We have checked the Wifi router's port, its open for port 5223.  do we need to open any other port?

Answer (score 0):

To send notifications, it's port 2195.